# Both 'Add-Migration' and 'Install-Package' are not recognised as an internal or external command. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools is installed

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-migrations, .net-7.0

Trying to run an initial migration on an .NET 7 ASP.NET API project, but receiving the error

> 'add-migration' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I have seen several similar threads on StackOverflow that recommend installing "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools", however this *is* installed.

I have tried:

- installing the package via .NET CLI, but receive the error 'install-package is not recognized as an internal or external command'
- Clear the nuget data cache.
- Clean-rebuild-restart Visual studio.

Unfortunately not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the commands in the **Package Manager Console** in Visual Studio.

[image]

Here is documentation about [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#installing-the-tools).

In your case:

Installing the package for EF Core

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Verify the installation

```
Get-Help about_EntityFrameworkCore
```

Adds a new migration.

```
Add-Migration Init
```

If you don't want to use the **Package Manager Console** and you prefer for example powershell you can use the [dotnet ef tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet).